# Cannot save changes to MS Word Master Document with sub-document

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

I have been trying to create a Microsoft Word 2016 Master Document for embedding multiple sub-documents following this [instruction](https://klariti.com/ms-word/how-to-create-master-documents/).

But after adding a sub-document I cannot save the master document. When I use the "save as" dialog no file gets created. When I create a master.docx file first and add any sub-document no changes are written to the master.docx. I have tested it with different sub-document files, but saving never works.

How can I save a master document?

Comment: First save all your sub-documents to some other folder also on your hdd. Then open master and add one or more sub-documents to it. Select expand documents. Now, leave that open, and go to the hdd and try to delete the sub-documents that you have already added in master document. If it gets deleted, it has not been added for some reason. (get the deleted document back from recycle bin or from the backup you made above). Had the sub-document been added, system would not allow you to delete it. If you are not allowed to delete it, then try to save master document after winding up. It should.

Comment: Yes, the sub documents have been added to the master document and can't be deleted while the master is open. However I cannot save the master after a document has been added and when I quit it, all changes are gone of course.

Comment: I have seen literature on this command say "leave a line gap between two added sub-documents" and "remove all section breaks" that you can do by going to view - Draft so that all section breaks are visible and then select each and delete. You can try these two modifications.

Comment: It doesn't help.